# Should I use the package "emmeans" for planned comparisons? Or should it be used only for post-hoc tests?

Tags: r, lsmeans, planned-comparisons-test

Because "emmeans" looks at all pairwise comparisons, I am asking myself if I should use the package for planned comparisons (I have hypotheses about the differences between certain groups).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "emmeans" for planned comparisons - it's just a matter of setting up your own custom contrasts (or comparisons).  Note that some people don't adjust for multiplicity when considering multiple planned comparisons, while others do.

You can refer to this excellent post by *Very statisticious* on **Custom contrasts in emmeans** for details on how to proceed:

https://aosmith.rbind.io/2019/04/15/custom-contrasts-emmeans/